# Error 948 on sql server 2008 when trying to attach semanticsDB

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search, semantic-analysis

When i'm trying to attach semanticsDB, it says that the database semanticsdb is version 693 but mine is 661.

Is there a way to run the semantic search (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492075.aspx) on a sql server 2008? Is there anything similar?

Thank you all.

Comment: You're trying to restore a DB from a version of SQL Server greater than the one you're running. That's not going to work. Semantic Search was only introduced/available in SQL Server 2012 onwards.

Comment: in fact this is what i'm supposing...some person above me is repeatedly telling me that this feature is available from sql server 2005...

Comment: Wriggle out from underneath them. [There is full-text-search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms142547(v=sql.100).aspx) but it's a little different / not as advanced.

Comment: i know full text search, in fact i've implemented it, by the way my goal was to see if two sentences are similar to each other, i've done something with a treetagger and wordnet..a slow code that tells you if a sentence is similar to another...but they want me to do with full text search...the only thing that is similar for me is the semantic search (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492075.aspx)